# Solution to a network SEIR ODE system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, network

I have the following network SEIR model:

\begin{align} 
        \frac{d}{dt} S_k(t) &= -\lambda kS_k(t) \Theta(t)\\\\
        \frac{d}{dt} E_k(t) &= \lambda kS_k(t) \Theta(t) - \varepsilon E_k(t)\\\\
        \frac{d}{dt} I_k(t) &= \varepsilon E_k(t) - \gamma I_k(t)\\\\
        \frac{d}{dt} R_k(t) &= \gamma I_k(t).
\end{align}

where $S_k(t), E_k(t), I_k(t), R_k(t)$ are densities of the population who are susceptible, exposed, infected, and removed at time $t$ for vertices of degree $k$; i.e. $S_k+ E_k+ I_k + R_k=1$. $\Theta(t)$ is the probability of having an infected neighbor given by

$$ \Theta(t) = \sum_{k} \frac{k P(k) I_{k}(t)}{\langle k \rangle}.$$

I have already solved the system but it doesn't really have a closed form solution so all I can do is solve it the best I can and interpret analytically. My problem is, I cannot seem to solve one equation (particularly the 2nd) and was wondering if anyone can help point out what is wrong or give direction to some other approach I could use to solve it.

Here are my solutions thus far:

\begin{align*}
    \int \frac{d}{dt} S_k(t) &= \int -\lambda kS_k(t) \Theta(t)\\\\ 
    \int \frac{dS_k(t)}{S_k(t)} &= -\lambda k \int \Theta(t) dt\\\\
    \ln S_k(t) &= -\lambda k \phi(t)\\\\
    S_k(t) &= e^{-\lambda k \phi(t)}
\end{align*}

where $\phi$ is the auxiliary function given by $$\phi(t) = \int \Theta(t') dt' = \frac{1}{\langle k \rangle} \int \sum_{k'} kP(k')I_{k'}(t) dt = \frac{\sum_{k'} kP(k')R_{k'}(t)}{\gamma \langle k \rangle}$$
Solution for $R_k(t)$
\begin{align*}
    \int \frac{d}{dt}R_k(t) &= \int \gamma I_k(t)\\\\
    \int dR_k(t) &= \gamma \int I_k(t) dt\\\\
    R_k(t) &= \gamma \int I_k(t)dt \qquad \longrightarrow \int I_k(t)dt = \frac{1}{\gamma} R_k(t)
\end{align*}
Solution for $I_k(t)$
\begin{align*}
    \int \frac{d}{dt}I_k(t) &= \int \varepsilon E_k(t) - \gamma I_k(t)\\\\
    \int dI_k(t) &= \int (\varepsilon E_k(t) - \gamma I_k(t))dt\\\\
    I_k(t) &= \varepsilon \int E_k(t)dt - \gamma \int I_k(t)dt\\\\
    I_k(t) &= \varepsilon \int E_k(t)dt - R_k(t) \qquad \longrightarrow \varepsilon \int E_k(t) = I_k(t)+R_k(t)
\end{align*}

Finally, the equation I cannot solve:
\begin{align*}
    \int \frac{d}{dt} E_k(t) &= \int \lambda kS_k(t) \Theta(t) - \varepsilon E_k(t)\\\\
    \int dE_k(t) &= \int \big( \lambda kS_k(t) \Theta(t) - \varepsilon E_k(t)\big) dt\\\\
    E_k(t) &= \int \lambda kS_k(t) \Theta(t)dt - \varepsilon \int E_k(t)dt\\\\
    E_k(t) + \varepsilon \int E_k(t)dt &= \lambda k \int S_k(t) \Theta(t)dt\\\\
    E_k(t) + I_k(t) + R_k(t) &= \lambda k \int S_k(t) \Theta(t)dt\\\\
    1-S_k(t) &= \lambda k \int S_k(t) \Theta(t)dt
\end{align*}

I do not know how to proceed from here. I was thinking if I could just have the integral $\int \Theta(t)dt$ then I could use the auxiliary function $\phi(t)$ but I do not know how.

Comment: Generally, there are no analytical solutions for nonlinear ODE systems.

Comment: @xpaul, would you say it would not be possible to get any expression from this as solution?

Comment: You can get something but not analytical solutions.